# How to rigorously differentiate the convolution of a distribution and a $L^2$ function?

Tags: sobolev-spaces, schwartz-distributions

I want to prove the following: (Here, $W^{2,2}$ is a Sobolev space as defined in [Evans](https://bookstore.ams.org/gsm-19-r), chapter 5; $S$ is a Schwartz space; and if $A$ is a distribution and $a$ a function, then $\langle A, a\rangle$ means $A(a)$).

> **Theorem.** Let $\newcommand{\C}{\mathbb C}\newcommand{\R}{\mathbb R}C\in]0,\infty[$. For every $f\in L^2 (\mathbb R;\C)$ there exists a $g\in (L^2 \cap W^{2,2}_{\text{loc}})(\R;\C)$ such that (in the weak sense)
> \begin{equation}
> -g'' + C^2 g = f
> \end{equation}
> and an explicit solution is given by
> \begin{equation}
> g(t) = \frac{1}{2C} \int_{\R} e^{-C|t-\tau|} f (\tau)\,\mathrm d\tau.
> \end{equation}

---

**My attempt.** (Skip to the bottom for my question)

Consider the tempered distribution
\begin{equation*}\begin{split}
    \mathscr Z: S(\R;\C)&\to\C, \\
    \phi&\mapsto\int_\R e^{-{C\lvert t\rvert}} \phi(t)\,\mathrm dt = \int_0^\infty e^{-Ct}\phi(t)\,\mathrm dt+\int_{-\infty}^0 e^{Ct} \phi(t)\,\mathrm dt.
\end{split}\end{equation*}
Then we have, for all $\phi\in S(\R;\C)$,
\begin{equation*}
\langle\mathscr Z',\phi\rangle=-\langle\mathscr Z,\phi'\rangle=\int_0^\infty e^{-Ct}\phi'(t)\,\mathrm dt+\int_{-\infty}^0 e^{Ct} \phi'(t)\,\mathrm dt.
\end{equation*}
Integrating both terms by parts, where the exponential term gets differentiated and $\phi'$ gets integrated, we get
\begin{equation*}\begin{split}
    -\langle\mathscr Z',\phi\rangle &= \left[e^{-Ct}\phi(t)\right]^\infty_0+C\int_0^\infty e^{-Ct}\phi(t)\,\mathrm dt+\left[e^{Ct}\phi(t)\right]^0_{-\infty}-C\int_{-\infty}^0 e^{Ct}\phi(t)\,\mathrm dt \\
    &= C\int_0^\infty e^{-Ct}\phi(t)\,\mathrm dt-C\int_{-\infty}^0 e^{Ct}\phi(t)\,\mathrm dt.
\end{split}\end{equation*}
Integrating both terms by parts in the same way, we get (where $\delta_0$ is the Dirac distribution at $0$)
\begin{equation*}\begin{split}
    \langle\mathscr Z'',\phi\rangle &= \langle-\mathscr Z',\phi'\rangle \\
    &= C\left[e^{-Ct}\phi(t)\right]^\infty_0+C^2\int_0^\infty e^{-Ct}\phi(t)\,\mathrm dt - \left(C \left[e^{Ct}\phi(t)\right]_{-\infty}^0-C^2\int_{-\infty}^0 e^{Ct}\phi(t)\,\mathrm dt\right) \\
    &= C^2 \langle\mathscr Z,\phi\rangle-2C\phi(0) = C^2 \langle\mathscr Z,\phi\rangle-2 C\langle{\delta_0,\phi}\rangle.
\end{split}\end{equation*}

---

Now I would like to finish by writing

$$g = \frac{\mathscr Z* f}{2C}$$ and therefore

$$-g''+C^2 g = \frac{-(\mathscr Z'' * f)+C^2 (\mathscr Z* f)}{2C}  = \frac{-((C^2\mathscr Z-2C\delta_0)*f)+C^2 (\mathscr Z* f)}{2C}=\delta_0*f = f.$$

**My question:** However, to do this, I formally use
$$ (A*a)'=(A'*a)$$
when $A$ is a distribution. Is there some result that justifies this? And furthermore, does this result also imply that $g$, defined as the convolution of $f$ with $\mathscr Z$, can be written as a $W^{2,2}_{\text{loc}}$ function?

Comment: do u know how $A'$ is defined?

Comment: You still have the usual (existence and uniqueness) theory available also for ODEs in this more general interpretation; this is discussed in many books, for example Coddington-Levinson. Your formula is then the variation-of-constants formula for the solutions of an inhomogeneous linear ODE.

Comment: @ChristianRemling Thank you! I will check out the Coddington-Levinson book that you mentioned in the next days

Comment: @mathworker21 Your question seems a bit supercilious, but that might be just me. In any case, the Definition that I am using is the following: If $T\in C^\infty_{\text c}(\mathbb R;\mathbb C)^*$, then $T'$ is the distribution given by $$\langle T',\phi\rangle = - \langle T,\phi\rangle.$$ If you have some great insight or if there is an elementary fact that I am missing that would allow me to use this in order to conclude that $$(\mathscr K * f)' = \mathscr K' * f,$$ I would be happy to hear it. Note that $f$ is in $L^2$, so a special property of $\mathscr K$ is used.

Comment: @mathworker21 (I do not know of a sensible way to define the convolution $T*f$ if $T$ is any tempered distribution and $f$ is any $L^2$-function.)

Comment: (And I meant to write $\langle T',\phi\rangle = - \langle T, \phi'\rangle$.)

Comment: @MaximilianJanisch nope, just an innocent question

Comment: If the convolution of distributions $f$ and $g$ is defined, then so is that of $Df$ (distibutional derivative) and $g$ and the expected formula holds.  This can be found in the article "Integrals and orders of growth of distributions" by J. Sebastião e Silva which can be found online and contains an elementary (freshman analysis level) treatment of distributions, their definite (partial) integrals and convolutions.

Comment: @mathworker21 ahh I apologize for getting a bit pissed then 

Comment: @bathalf15320 Thank you, I will look it up soon!

Comment: @bathalf15320 I was not able to find the article (all I found is [this page](https://searchworks.stanford.edu/view/2147038) where you can demand Stanford library to scan it for you, but it seems that is only for Stanford students). Do you have a hint for me?

Comment: Sebastão e silva's complete works are available at the site

Comment: Sebastião e Silva's articles are available at the site

Comment: jss100.campus.ciencias.ulisboa.pt where you will find the proceedings of a conference at Lisbon which include the article I referenced. I would recommend that you continue to publicações/textosdidacticos where you will find an accessible treatment to his approach to distributions, based on lectures he gave in Maryland.

Comment: @bathalf15320 Thank you so much! I'll try to update you on if I found what I needed in the near future.

Comment: @bathalf15320 Indeed I found what I needed (see my answer below).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The last step is formally justified by **15.8, differentiation property** of José Sebastião e Silva's "Integrals and orders of growth of distributions." (The paper is currently available [here](http://jss100.campus.ciencias.ulisboa.pt/Publicacoes/Artigos-de-Investigacao/Inv-JSS/Integrals%20and%20orders%20of%20growth%20of%20distributions.pdf).)

More precisely: $\mathscr K$ is defined by a continuous function. Also, by Lemma 8.2 of Haim Brezis' *Functional Analysis, Sobolev Spaces and Partial Differential Equations* (2010), we have, in the weak sense, since $f\in L^2\subset L^1_{\text{loc}}$, $F'=f$ where $F(x):=\int_0^x f$ is continuous.

Therefore, one can indeed apply 15.8 mentioned above.